# Java 11 SpringBoot Application Error When Deployed on TomEE 7.1.0 Server

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-tomee, java-11, tomee-7

We are migrating our SpringBoot appliation from Java 1.8 to Java 11.
The new environment is:

1. Java version = 11.0.1+13
2. SpringBoot version = 2.1.1.RELEASE
3. TomEE version = 7.1.0

I have created a sample project with only single controller class for the simplicity for posting here on SO:

HelloController.java

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/greet")
public class HelloController {
    @GetMapping
    public String greetings() {
        return "Hello, world!!!";
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>SampleJava11</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>SampleJava11</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>11</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I get the following error when TomEE startup.bat is executed:

```
14-Mar-2019 16:23:30.408 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.removeChild: destroy:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: An invalid Lifecycle transition was attempted ([before_destroy]) for component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleJava11]] in state [STARTING_PREP]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.invalidTransition(LifecycleBase.java:402)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.removeChild(ContainerBase.java:856)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1651)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeploy(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1631)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.undeployWebApps(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:764)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.destroyApplication(Assembler.java:2406)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1089)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

14-Mar-2019 16:23:30.444 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal Unable to deploy collapsed ear in war StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleJava11]
 org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: E:\Programs\tomee\webapps\SampleJava11: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1093)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.__privileged_doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder$OpenEjbConfig.buildValidatorFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:67)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:972)
    ... 17 more

14-Mar-2019 16:23:30.445 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke ContainerBase.addChild: start:
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleJava11]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:754)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomEERuntimeException: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: E:\Programs\tomee\webapps\SampleJava11: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1315)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1125)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:133)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.apache.openejb.OpenEJBException: Creating application failed: E:\Programs\tomee\webapps\SampleJava11: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:1093)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:754)
    at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1303)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.validation.spi.ConfigurationState.getValueExtractors()Ljava/util/Set;
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl.<init>(ValidatorFactoryImpl.java:140)
    at org.hibernate.validator.HibernateValidator.buildValidatorFactory(HibernateValidator.java:38)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.__privileged_doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:332)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.doBuildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java)
    at org.apache.bval.jsr.ConfigurationImpl.buildValidatorFactory(ConfigurationImpl.java:324)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder$OpenEjbConfig.buildValidatorFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:401)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:111)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.ValidatorBuilder.buildFactory(ValidatorBuilder.java:67)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.ensureDelegate(LazyValidatorFactory.java:54)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.LazyValidatorFactory.getFactory(LazyValidatorFactory.java:65)
    at org.apache.openejb.assembler.classic.Assembler.createApplication(Assembler.java:972)
    ... 17 more

14-Mar-2019 16:23:30.445 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke Error deploying web application archive [E:\Programs\tomee\webapps\SampleJava11.war]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/SampleJava11]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:758)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:730)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:985)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I couldn't figure out why simple war with single controller is not failing. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Why would you even want to deploy spring apps on a EE server ? Make sure you are not packaging server provided classes in your WAR file. Basically spring is very invasive and packages tons of stuff that it must not package. Also check if you are compiling against the correct API versions - spring may require incompatible versions.

Comment: The deployment environment is finalized by people from Service Architecture team and I am not aware why EE server is chosen (as I am quite new to the Service/backend development itself). Out of curiosity, what type of server would you suggest to be used with springboot.


About your suggestion to check for packages, I found out that hibernate-validator is causing the exception, though I have not used anything from hibernate package in my Sample project. After excluding the dependency from pom.xml, now it is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

I've faced this issue before, look at your lib folder inside WEB-INF of your .war (WEB-IN/lib) you will find two validators jar, so that create some conflict, remove the last one (hibernate-validator) and keep the "validation-api".
this fixed my issue